# Need help to convert a SKP file into an OBJ without having sketchup PRO

Tags: file-format, obj

I would like to get an SKP object into my blender project but unfortunately I don't have a sketchup subscription, so I can't convert it in sketchup.
So I wanted to ask if someone in this community has a sketchup subscription, who could convert the file into an OBJ for me...

Here is the link to the .skp object  I am talking about:
[https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model/f2d5f47e563436a4631a5b7d7e03136/Olympiastadion-München?hl=de#contact](https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model/f2d5f47e563436a4631a5b7d7e03136/Olympiastadion-M%C3%BCnchen?hl=de#contact)

I am very thankful if someone could send me this as an OBJ file somehow...

Kind regards Matteo

Comment: You can try this addon https://blenderartists.org/t/sketchup-importer-v0-23-released/1223412/93

Comment: Unfortunately I can't enable the add on btw. I am using macOS so that might be a problem... are there any other ways?